# Trail-type effect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to accomplish a sort of trail effect when the block is highlighted heres a picture: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blarE.png)

I try changing the image, but to accomplish what I want is it to select the next one over, then change back to white, for instance if the first tile is blue, but you want to third to be, it would not be blue on the first, then turn blue on the second, then white, THEN the third. I hope this makes sense. Here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inside_blue"];
_t1.image = image;
wait = @"yes";
}


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)move:(id)sender {
UIImage *imageblue = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inside_blue"];
UIImage *imagewhite = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inside_white"];
_t1.image = imagewhite;
_t2.image = imageblue;
[self performSelector:@selector(waitTime) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
while ([wait isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
    //hi
}
_t2.image = imagewhite;
_t3.image = imageblue;
[self performSelector:@selector(waitTime2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
while ([wait2 isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
    //hi
}
_t3.image = imagewhite;
_t4.image = imageblue;

}

- (void)waitTime2 {

wait2 = @"no";

}


- (void)waitTime {

wait = @"no";

}
```

But that just freezes the app.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this freezes the app. Drawing is done, when the app returns to the run loop and can deliver drawing events.

You have to write the code "asynchronously", store the actual state to the view object and trigger the redraw. after setting up a timer, you will return to the code, set the next state and trigger drawing again. I recommend that you read the introduction to drawing. The whole explanation would be too much for an answer on SO.

Likely it is easier to implement the whole move as an animatable property. The timing and redraws would be executed automatically in this case.